# Powerbuilder .net adds \ escape character for double quotes in string variable:pfc_n_cst_winsrv_statusbar

Tags: .net, escaping, powerbuilder, double-quotes, backslash

Essentially `pfc_n_cst_winsrv_statusbar.of_createdwobject` generates a datawindow definition in `ls_dwdefinition`, then uses that to create a datawindow. I'm testing this using the PFC Example app, with the latest 12.5 Classic PFC pbls. This works in PB Classic 12.5.2 Build 5006. Migrated that app to PB .net 12.5.2 Build 5006. This does not work in PB .net. When generating the datawindow definition in `ls_dwdefinition`, PB .net inserts `\` escape characters in front of all double quotes embedded in `ls_dwdefinition`. The subsequent creation of the datawindow fails (see error following) I assume because the `\` escape characters are not recognized as valid dw syntax. I compared the dwsyntax string created in PB Classic 12.5 vs the PB .net created dw syntax string, and the only differences I can see are `\` escape characters.

Has anyone seen this behavior before? Is there a setting I could change that would eliminate this behavior? Any help would be greatly appreciated. BTW, this is not just an exercise, I originally saw this behavior in our proprietary app which is being migrated to PB .net.

Regards,

Todd Oesterreich

> System.Exception: Incorrect syntax\r\n   at
>   Sybase.DataWindow.Core.DWObject.ParseInt(String value)\r\n   at
>   Sybase.DataWindow.Core.DWDataWindow.SetProperty(String name, String
>   value)\r\n   at Sybase.DataWindow.Core.SrdParser.a(IDWObject A_0,
>   String A_1, String A_2)\r\n   at
>   Sybase.DataWindow.Core.SrdParser.value(IDWObject prop, String nm)\r\n 
>   at Sybase.DataWindow.Core.SrdParser.name_value_pair(IDWObject
>   prop)\r\n   at Sybase.DataWindow.Core.SrdParser.property()\r\n   at
>   Sybase.DataWindow.Core.SrdParser.srd_definition()\r\n   at
>   Sybase.DataWindow.Core.DWSrdSyntaxReader.Parse(DWObject parent, String
>   syntax, DWParserOptions parserOptions)\r\n   at
>   Sybase.DataWindow.Core.DWDataWindowObject.a(DWSrdSyntaxReader A_0,
>   String A_1, DWParserOptions A_2, String& A_3, DWDataWindowObject& A_4)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to parse through the dwsyntax and strip off the added slashes prior to using it to create the dw?

Comment: Matt, yes I have done (tried) that, something internally adds the escape characters back in! For instance, I've stripped out the \'s in textpad, copied that to the clipboard, pasted that into the ls_dwdefinition variable while in a debug session, internally the \'s get reapplied as the paste operation happens.

Comment: What about programatically removing the \ from the string and then trying to create the dw?

Comment: I tried that, when I search for occurrences of \" with the pos function, it doesn't find it. I suppose I could search for the " itself, and then concatenate the string to the left of the leading \ with the string to the right of the leading backslash. I'm almost certain that won't work though the backslash is only recognized internally. For instance if you assign '"' to a string variable, and look at it in the debugger, it will display as "\"". But if you then display that string var in a messagebox, it only displays the ". (continued)

Comment: An exception to that "internal" recognition seems to be when the variable with the datawindow definition is passed to the create function, the backslashes seem to be pushed through with the rest of the datawindow definition.

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured this out (with a little help from my friends pointing me away from my \ escape character “guesses”)

Turns out there are a couple code bugs in the pfc_n_cst_winsrv_statusbar.of_createdwobject function. But apparently the PB Classic compiler is more forgiving than PB .net.

1) the DW color attribute is butting up directly against the DW timer_interval attribute, there should be a space between the 2 attributes, PB Classic seemed OK with this and would still create the DW, PB .net spits it back though.

```
// Create the desired DataWindow Timer Interval.    
If ib_timer Then    
            // A timer event is defined. Use the appropriate value.    
            ls_dwtimerinterval = 'timer_interval=' + string(il_timerinterval)    
Else    
            // No timer event is defined.    
            ls_dwtimerinterval = 'timer_interval=0 '    
End If

// Create the Header string.    
ls_header = &  
  'release 6; '+ &  
  'datawindow(units=0 '+ &  
  ls_dwtimerinterval + &  
'color=80263328 processing=0 HTMLDW=no print.documentname="" ' + &  
  'print.orientation = 0 print.margin.left = 107 print.margin.right = 107 ' + &  
  'print.margin.top = 97 print.margin.bottom = 97 print.paper.source = 0 ' + &  
  'print.paper.size = 0 print.prompt=no print.buttons=no print.preview.buttons=no) ' + &  
  'header(height=' + string(li_microhelpheight) + ' color="536870912" ) ' + &  
  'summary(height=1 color="536870912" ) ' + &  
  'footer(height=1 color="536870912" ) ' + &  
  'detail(height=1 color="536870912" ) ' + &  
  'table(column=(type=char(20) updatewhereclause=no name=requiredcol dbname="requiredcol" ) ) '
```

2) When compiling the above fix we got several “cannot apply a unary operator to a string variable” errors. The big red plus below is not valid PB syntax, but PB Classic seems OK with it, basically ignores it, PB .net not so nice, treats it as what it is, a unary operator.

CHOOSE CASE Lower(inv_dwobjects[li_cnt].s_type)
    CASE TEXT
        ls_newobject = + &
            'compute( '+ &
            'name=' + inv_dwobjects[li_cnt].s_id + ' ' + &
            'expression="~'' + string(inv_dwobjects[li_cnt].s_value) + '~'" '+ &
            'border="' + string(inv_dwobjects[li_cnt].i_bordertype) +'" ' + &
            'x="' + string(li_xpoint) + '" ' + &
            'height="'+string(li_microhelpheight)+'" ' + &
            'width="'+ string(inv_dwobjects[li_cnt].i_width) + '" ' + &
            'background.color="12632256" ' +&
            'band=header alignment="0"  color="33554432" y="0" '+  &
            'font.face="MS Sans Serif" font.height="-8" font.weight="400" '+ &
            'font.family="2" font.pitch="2" font.charset="0" background.mode="2"                    ' +&  ') '